# Android - Any library for adding repost label to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have been trying to make a photo sharing app, with the ability to add your image and name to the image. I have been messing with Canvas for the whole day, but couldn't get good results. I was able to draw the name and bitmap, but they didn't look so good.

That's why I am here asking about is there any library or piece of code that could help me in making something similar to [this][1]. I wasn't able to find any thing for it.

EDIT: Sorry for not adding my own code

Here is my code from my latest try

```
public void AddText(Position2D pos){
//Position2D is an enum having the 4 corners of the image
    bmWorking= bmOriginal.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmWorking);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    float width = (35f/100f) * bmWorking.getWidth();
    float height = (width/16f) * 3;
    textPaint.setTextSize(height - 4);  //I wanted to have some space (margin) above and below the text
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float [] coords = getPositionCoords(pos, width, height);  //getPositionCoords returns a float array with the Left,Top,Right,Bottom position calculated based on the width and height
    canvas.drawRect(coords[0],coords[1], coords[2], coords[3],paint);
    username = "Haider Ali Punjabi";
    canvas.drawText(username, coords[0] ,coords[3], textPaint);
    bitmapView.setImageBitmap(bmWorking);

}
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNQ9I.png)

**UPDATE:**
@pskink gave me [this code](http://pastebin.com/JFYbDNLc)
 which works nicely

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and ask the controversial "What have you tried?" question here.

Comment: @Shark I haven't tried any library. But I have tried using Canvas and drawing a bitmap over the photo. I got the bitmap by using .getDrawingCache on a relative layout. It worked, but it used to take more space in low res photos. I added scaling to it, it used to take same space, but scaling caused its quality to go down. I also tried drawing the text, background rectangle and the bitmap but wasn't able to fit the bitmap and the text within the rectangle.

Comment: `"but wasn't able to fit the bitmap and the text within the rectangle"`, what rectangle do you mean?

Comment: @pskink a rectangle that I created by drawRect(), I know I could have set the width by measuring how much space the text would take, but I want the rectangle to take 35% of the width of the photo, so I can only reduce the size of the text, which doesn't look good

Comment: so the longer text would need to be broken into several lines?

Comment: @pskink it's not that long, around the same length as in the example

Comment: so if the text fits 35% why would you want to reduce the size of the text?

Comment: In this particular case, your code will explain better than your words

Comment: @Shark, I added my latest code

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/JFYbDNLc

Comment: @pskink I haven't tried it yet, will try it today and update here

Comment: @pskink It works thanks. And you gave enough code for me to customize

Comment: of course you dont have to use `android.R.drawable.*` only: you can use your custom, own `R.drawable.*` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to customize it, then instead of solid white rectangle (like in your original code) use a `Drawable` and the result could be something like this:

[image]

the code:

```
// for int gravity: see android.view.Gravity, like Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.BOTTOM, etc
// for example:
// Bitmap out = addText(this, in, "Haider Ali Punjabi", android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame, Gravity.BOTTOM, new Point(10, 10));
public Bitmap addText(Context ctx, Bitmap in, String text, int resId, int gravity, Point pad) {
    if (pad == null) pad = new Point();

    Bitmap out = in.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(out);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
//    textPaint.setTextSize(128);

    Rect inBounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), inBounds);
    float scale = out.getWidth() * 0.35f / inBounds.width();

    Rect container = new Rect(0, 0, out.getWidth(), out.getHeight());
    Rect outBounds = new Rect();
    int w = (int) (inBounds.width() * scale);
    int h = (int) (inBounds.height() * scale);
    Gravity.apply(gravity, 2 * pad.x + w, 2 * pad.y + h, container, outBounds);

    Drawable dr = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    Rect padding = new Rect();
    dr.getPadding(padding);
    dr.setBounds(outBounds.left - padding.left, outBounds.top - padding.top, outBounds.right + padding.right, outBounds.bottom + padding.bottom);
    dr.draw(canvas);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF src = new RectF(inBounds);
    RectF dst = new RectF(outBounds);
    dst.inset(pad.x, pad.y);
    matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    canvas.concat(matrix);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, textPaint);
    return out;
}
```