# Center text inside it's boundaries (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, text, fonts, bitmap

So I'm trying to center a text within it's boundaries. I'm creating a bitmap the size of which is relative to letter String boundaries.

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), bounds);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.width() + 1, (int)(paint.descent() - paint.ascent()), Config.ARGB_8888); //+1 to prevent width = 0, which throws exception
```

Then I draw the string to that bitmap.

```
canvas.drawText(s, 1, (i)*paint.descent() - (i+1)*paint.ascent(), paint);
```

The problem is  that with some Typefaces like https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/alex-brush some letters are partially cut off. The bitmap width seems to be alright but letters aren't drawn to the center.

```
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

makes it even worse.

The image below is result of using the code and typeface above with paint's default textAlignment. Drawn String is "j".
[image: Letter 'j' is partially cut off using the above code and typeface]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42480830/2252830, notice `canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, textPaint);` of course instead of `canvas.concat(matrix);` you can also use `Matrix#mapPoints` method to get mapped coords

Comment: @pskink Thank you, that seems to be just what I needed! :) +1

Comment: but honestly in your case (when you are not scaling your drawn text) you could simply use `-bounds.left` and `-bounds.top` as `x` and `y` params in `canvas.drawText`, check it out (no `Matrix` needed)

Comment: so your code could be as simple as: `canvas.drawText(s, -bounds.left, -bounds.top, paint);`

Comment: Ohh, true :) Thank you. That's more convenient in this case.

Comment: and create your Bitmap of size [bounds.width(), bounds.height()] (plus one pixel if you really want)