# How to add a text to an image?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, imageview

If some one click on 'share on whatsapp' in Instagram, the image will automatically add the user name in that photo. How can I make it.

Hope you understood what I mean.
If not then please open the Instagram app and click 'share on whatsapp' or 'share on messenger' of any post on your feed, you will understand.

Comment: Open the instagram app and share any post to whatsapp('share on whatsapp').....you will understand what I mean

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480830/2252830)

Answer (score 0):

you set textview below imageview and set visibility to be **gone** , then when you upload the image set the ***visiblity*** to be **visible**  and set text what ever you want in this textview

Comment: How to combine two images....when user saved the image....I want to merge those images...how can it possible

Comment: what do you mean with merge ?

Comment: Here Merge means join